# Terminal to manage cluster, where the nodes are accessible from a remote PC?

Tags: ssh, cluster, cluster-ssh

I need to manage multiple cluster nodes from my PC. The catch is that the cluster nodes are accessible only from a remote PC. So first I have to ssh to the remote PC, and then ssh to a cluster node from the remote PC.

If I had direct access to the nodes, I would use something like clusterssh to manage all the nodes simultaneously.

Is there a tool similar to clusterssh that I can use in my situation?

Comment: And you can't install clusterssh on the remote PC, for example? What about using the hop machine (the remote PC) to run something like Tmux or screen and inside of that use clusterssh as you normally would?

Comment: @0xC0000022L The remote PC has no graphical interface.

Comment: Uhm, what's that got to do with it? `clusterssh` controls multiple xterm windows on your local system (which you could install X11 on). alternatively you can use the feature in tmux which lets you synchronize the input across panes (within the same window). So all you'd have to do is connect to your remote machines using SSH within a Tmux session running on your local box.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked together a 'cluster screen' thing to do something similar.  You setup the `/etc/clusters` file the same way as clusterssh

```
cluster1 host1 host2
cluster2 host3 host4
```

Then I have a file at `/usr/local/bin/cs` (a mild rip-off of the cssh name :) that looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# < 1 ]]
then
   echo -e "Usage : $0 cluster [command]";
   exit;
fi;

cluster=$(/bin/grep $1 /etc/clusters | sed -e 's/[^\ ]*\ //')

for s in $cluster; do
    if [ -n "$2" ]
    then
        exec screen -t "$s" $s "$2";
    else
        exec screen -t "$s" $s;
    fi
done;
```

Then you can run

```
screen
cs clustername "optional command"
```

It's not quite as nice as clusterssh but it gets the job done

Comment: Can you please specify what config files go in the remote PCs vs the local PC?

Comment: @becko In the setup from the OP you're at computer A, you ssh into computer B and from there you're able to ssh into all of the nodes in the cluster.  All of the configs in my answer go on computer B.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, nope you don't have to `ssh` first to one machine and then to another. Not even on old `ssh` clients would you have to do such a thing.

I have a similar scenario to yours, although I am not interested in entering the exact same command on a number of remote machines.

I was asking in my comment because you pose a question without giving full details. So let me make some assumptions. I will assume your **local box** to have Tmux and `ssh` (the client) installed in a reasonably recent version. If it hasn't, because it's Windows for example, use a VM. I will also assume that your "remote PC", to which I will refer as the **jump host**, has `ssh` installed as well and can be reached *from* your local box and can *reach* the **cluster nodes** in turn. We'll have `node1` through `node5` as our cluster nodes. Then `localbox` and `jumphost` for the two others involved.

Now with the terminology out of the way, open up [this link to ssh_config(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) and switch to it whenever something of the following becomes unclear.

In your home folder on `localbox` open `.ssh/config` in your favorite text editor. Create the `~/.ssh` folder if needed. Then enter the following:

```
Host jumphost
    HostName the.name.of.your.jumphost.tld
    ForwardAgent yes # YMMV

Host node1 node 2 node3 node4 node5
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost
```

This tells `ssh` that in order to connect to `node1` through `node5` it has to first connect to `jumphost` and forward/proxy to another host:

> `-W host:port`
>   Requests that standard input and output on the client be forwarded to host on
>   port over the secure channel.  Implies `-N`, `-T`, `ExitOnForwardFailure` and
>   `ClearAllForwardings`. Works with Protocol version 2 only.

If you have a particularly old version of the `ssh` on the `jumphost` (i.e. not supporting `-W`), *but* netcat (`nc`) is installed, you can substitute the `ProxyCommand` as appropriate with:

```
ProxyCommand ssh user@proxy nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Now once the above lines are in the text file, add one per cluster node as appropriate:

```
Host node1 node1.cluster.domain.tld
    HostKeyAlias node1.cluster.domain.tld
    HostName 1.2.3.4 # you can give IPs
```

This assumes, that the name of the `node1` isn't public or known to your `localbox` and can't be looked up either. But the IP is known. `HostKeyAlias` ensures that at a later point you can switch from `HostName $IP` to an actual hostname instead. I also tend to shorten the alias to `node1.cluster` or similar, in case the top-level domains ever change.

So for `node2` we may have a public DNS record:

```
Host node2 node2.cluster.otherdomain.tld
    HostKeyAlias node2.cluster
    HostName node2.cluster.otherdomain.tld # ... or hostnames
```

And that lets you now use either (recommended):

```
ssh node1
ssh node2
```

or (not recommended):

```
ssh node`.cluster.domain.tld
ssh node2.cluster.otherdomain.tld
```

to connect to these nodes *via* the `jumphost`. It also allows you to connect to the `jumphost` by simply typing `ssh jumphost`.

It's important to understand here, that the name as it appears on the `Host` line is completely independent of the DNS name or IP, *provided* a `HostName` line exists for that `Host` line. IIRC indentation is convention, but not necessary.

Now the only thing on the SSH side to sort out is authentication. You can explicitly give a `User` in each of these "blocks" to connect using an alternative username. And you need to decide if you trust the `jumphost` enough to activate agent forwarding. If you don't, you'll have to create a key on `jumphost` and make it known to your cluster nodes (in `.ssh/authorized_keys`). Anything else would prompt you for passwords too often.

To summarize everything until now, but alternating on the idea which user connects where:

```
Host jumphost
    HostName the.name.of.your.jumphost.tld
    User joe

Host node1 node 2 node3 node4 node5
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost
    User joseph

Host node1 node1.cluster.domain.tld
    HostKeyAlias node1.cluster.domain.tld
    HostName 1.2.3.4 # you can give IPs
    User root

Host node2 node2.cluster.otherdomain.tld
    HostKeyAlias node2.cluster
    HostName node2.cluster.otherdomain.tld # ... or hostnames
```

... would, upon `ssh node1`, connect as `joe@jumphost` to forward a connection `root@node1`. And, upon `ssh node2`, connect as `joe@jumphost` to forward a connection `joseph@node2`.

So you can override some of the configuration file stanzas per host.

---

With the SSH part out of the way, let's turn to running commands in parallel.

You should be able to orchestrate multiple xterm windows using `clusterssh` after the respective xterm windows have established SSH connections to the cluster nodes. However, I personally would find this cumbersome and rather unintuitive.

You have many options. Those I propose all require only a single terminal on your `localbox`.

You can use `dsh` (dancer's/distributed shell) or dish (diligence/distributed shell) for one.

`pssh` (parallel `ssh`) is another option, but it's Python-based so its ability to parse `.ssh/config` - from experience - can be limiting.

Last, but certainly not least, I would recommend [Tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) to you. Short for "terminal multiplexer" it falls into the same category as GNU `screen`, but is far better than `screen`.

I for one have a shortcut for synchronizing the panes in a single Tmux window with <kbd>Ctrl+a S</kbd> (where <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> is my preferred prefix).

```
bind-key S set-window-option synchronize-panes \; display-message 'Toggled synchronize-panes'
```

With that you could open one SSH connection per pane inside one Tmux window and synchronize input to all of them. This would allow you to type a command into all panes in a Tmux window (a window is essentially like a tab in Tmux terminology) and execute it at once with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Keep in mind, however, that this may work fine for a handful of remote nodes, but will become unwieldy with higher numbers. So after all you may want to look into one of the other solutions I recommended.